# Post to /upload from react native

Tags: react-native, strapi

I'm trying to upload a picture to strapi from react native.

```
async function uploadPicture(uri) {
  var data = new FormData();
    data.append('files', {
      uri: uri.replace('file://', ''),
      name: uri,
      type: 'image/jpg'
    });

    // Create the config object for the POST
    // You typically have an OAuth2 token that you use for authentication
    const config = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'
      },
      body: data
    };

    const fetchPromise = fetch('http://<host>:1337/upload', config)
    console.log(fetchPromise)
    return await fetchPromise
 }
```

I get a 200 status code but no new picture is listed on the uploads page.

Comment: Excuse me picture upload success to server? and you just want to update list in client?

Comment: Strapi returns status 200 but does not update the uploads list. However when I use curl it works fine.

Comment: Shouldn't my code work in react native ios?

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I figured it out using simple-http-upload-server to test the uploads. The problem was that I was setting the name of the file to be the uri. This would probably cause an error on strapi when creating the file on the server folder. It should return an error code nonetheless.